# Address of a pointer is equal to a pointer to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm trying to understand how the pointers in this piece of code works:

```
void allocateArray( int **arr, size_t size, int value )
{
    *arr = malloc( size * sizeof( int ));

    if ( *arr != NULL )
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
            *( *arr + i ) = value;
}

int main( void )
{
    int *vector = NULL;

    allocateArray(&vector,5,45);

    free( vector );

    return 0;
}
```

If I declared a pointer to an int ( *vector ), how passing its address makes it a pointer to a pointer to int ( **arr )? I mean, how does it work, now that vector's address in the memory will be overwritten!

Comment: The vector's address will *not* be overwritten - the value of `vector` (which initially is `NULL`) will be overwritten.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - if it is like that, why can't I pass the pointer itself to the function like this: allocateArray( vector, 5, 45 );

Comment: @KaeLL: Because `allocateArray` requires an `int**`, and `vector` is an `int*`; the types are incompatible.

Comment: @KaeLL: If you do that, then you're just passing the value of `vector` which is `NULL`, which you can't use inside `allocateArray()`. If you really want to pass the value of `vector`, it should have a value pointing to a memory pre-allocated before calling `allocateArray()`, remove `malloc()` inside `allocateArray()`, and make the proper dereference.

Comment: `If I declared a pointer to an int ( *vector ), how passing its address makes it a pointer to a pointer to int ( **arr )?`: because declaring `int *vector` makes `vector` a pointer to `int`, it's address, `&vector`, is also a pointer, making it a `pointer to an int pointer` (pointer to a pointer to int).

Comment: Yes, I know that! But @RichardJ.RossIII said that the value will be overwritten! but how can that be if I'm passing <code>&vector</code> and not <code>vector</code> ? And if I declare <code>int **vector;</code>, why it doesn't work passing int like this: <code>allocateArray( vector, 5, 45 );</code> ??

Comment: `I mean, how does it work, now that vector's address in the memory will be overwritten!`: vector's address is never overwritten; what is overwritten, however, is the contents of the vector's address when you did `*arr = malloc( size * sizeof( int ));` inside `allocateArray()`.

Comment: @KaeLL: Passing vector when you declared it as `int **vector = NULL` still giving `allocateArray()` an `arr = NULL`. You can't dereference a NULL, `*(NULL), *(0)`. If however, you assigned a valid address to vector, `int **vector = 0x12345678`, then it will work. But then again, you still need a valid address. One valid address is the address of `int *vector`, `&vector`.

Comment: @n3rd4n1: And if I want to pass this pointer to a 3rd function? I mean, if there was another function, and I want to pass `**arr` to it! Its argument should be, for instance, something like `int ***arr2`, and I should call it `functionX( &arr );` ??

Comment: @KaeLL: Yes, that would be the case if you want to change the contents of `**arr` inside `functionX()`. If not, you can still do it like that or just let `functionX()` accept an `int **arr2` variable and pass `arr` to it.

Comment: Now I know why people run away from pointers! :)

Answer (score 3):

C passes function parameters by value. So, to allow a function to modify a variable provided by the caller, a pointer to it must be passed. And the function must dereference the pointer to make the modification.

```
void foo_1 (int a) {
    a += 1;   /* caller will not see any change to a */
}

void foo_2 (int *ap) {
    *ap += 1; /* caller will see value has changed */
}

int a = 0;
foo_1(a);  /* a is still 0 after return */
foo_2(&a); /* a becomes 1 after return */
```

The `&` operator results in a value that represents the address to the object it is applied to, and the resulting type is "pointer to (type of the object)". In the above example, the result of `&a` is "pointer to `int`".

Nothing is fundamentally different if the variable is a pointer type.

```
void foo_1 (int *a) {
    a = malloc(sizeof(int));   /* caller will not see any change to a */
}

void foo_2 (int **ap) {
    *ap = malloc(sizeof(int)); /* caller will see value has changed */
}

int *a = 0;
foo_1(a);  /* a is still 0 after return */
foo_2(&a); /* a becomes initialized to memory allocated by malloc */
```

In the above example, since `a` is a pointer to `int`, type of `&a` is "pointer to pointer to `int`".

---

A *pointer* is a term that is used to refer to the address of an object. The address of an object is a value that represents where the object resides in memory. Knowing that address means the object can be read and modified. A *pointer variable* is a variable that can store the address of an object.

Normally, the name of a variable is used to represent the object. By object, I just mean the memory used by the variable, and its semantic representation, aka, its type (often, the terms variable and object are used interchangeably, but to me, the difference is that a variable has a name). Reading and modifying the object is done through the name. One way to obtain a pointer to an object is to apply the unary `&` operator to the name of a variable. A pointer variable holding that address is thus a pointer to that object. And now, that same object can be read and modified via the pointer by dereferencing the pointer, using the unary `*` operator.

```
int a = 0;
int *ap = &a;
a += 1;       /* a now has the value 1 */
*ap += 1;     /* a now has the value 2 */
```

A dynamically created object, i.e. through `malloc()`, does not have a name. But, `malloc()` returns a pointer through which the object can be read and modified.

```
int *ap = 0;              /* ap initialized to NULL */
ap = malloc(sizeof(int)); /* ap points to dynamically allocated int */
*ap = 0;                  /* int pointed to by ap now holds value 0 */
*ap += 1;                 /* int pointed to by ap now holds value 1 */
```

Your `allocateArray()` function combines both of these uses of a pointer into a single function.

```
int *vector = NULL;          /* vector is pointer to int variable initialized to NULL */
allocateArray(&vector,5,45); /* the address of vector is passed to allocateArray */
```

Since the address of vector is passed to `allocateArray()`, that function now has the means to modify the object named `vector` by derferencing the pointer value it received. The pointer value is received in the `arr` argument:

```
void allocateArray( int **arr, size_t size, int value )
```

And, by dereferencing `arr`, it is updating the `vector` object with the value returned by `malloc()`:

```
*arr = malloc( size * sizeof( int ));
```

Perhaps the function would have been more clear if the allocation, initialization of the memory, and then the update of the `vector` variable happened in multiple steps.

```
void allocateArray( int **arr, size_t size, int value )
{
    int *vec = malloc( size * sizeof( int ));  /* vec points to size contiguous int */

    if ( vec != NULL )
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
            vec[i] = value;                    /* vec[i] set to value */

    *arr = vec;                                /* return vec into first parameter */
}
```

Comment: So, inside foo_2, I could use '**a' to allocate, for instance, not only a vector, but an array?

Comment: In `foo_2`, before the call the `malloc`, `*ap` is 0. So `**ap` dereferences 0, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

**Some background:**

Parameters in C are always passed by value.  For example, consider the code

```
void some_func(int i) { i = i + 2; printf("i = %d\n", i); }

void main_func() {
  int n = 5;
  some_func(n);
  printf("n = %d\n", n);
}
```

**Output:**

```
 i = 7
 n = 5
```

The main function passes the value 5 to `some_func`, which changes its own local copy in `i` but cannot change `n` in the calling function.

Now, suppose you want to write a function that *does* change the caller's value.  You can do this by passing the *address* of the variable you want to change:

```
void new_func(int *i) { *i = *i + 2; printf("*i = %d\n", *i); }

void main_func() {
  int n = 5;
  some_func(&n);
  printf(" n = %d\n", n);
}
```

**Output:**

```
 *i = 7
  n = 7
```

The "trick" is that `new_func` doesn't change the value of its parameter; it changes some other value -- the variable its parameter *points* to.  So the rule is:

**If you want a function to alter a variable, you pass the *address* of that variable.**

In other words, **if you want a function to change `foo`, you pass a *pointer* to `foo`.**

---

**Application to your code:**

The `main` function declared a pointer, `vector`, that has no memory allocated to it.  Its value is `NULL`.  It calls `allocateArray()` to allocate memory and assign it to `vector`.  But that means it must *change* the value of `vector` from `NULL` to the address of the newly-allocated memory.  Following the same rule as above, in order to change `vector`, you need to pass its *address* to `allocateArray()`.  And since `vector` is of type pointer-to-int, its address is of type pointer-to-pointer-to-int.

To be clear: you haven't changed the type of `vector`; you've simply passed its address.  So within `allocateArray()`, `arr` is of type `int **`, and `*arr` is of type `int *`.  Syntactically, you use `*arr` exactly as you would use `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

So vector is a pointer to an int, so the address of vector is a pointer to a pointer to an int(&vector is equivalent to int **). vector = *arr, not &vector = *arr. Therefore vector is gets the address that the call to malloc returns, not the address of vector. I think the confusion is between the address of vector and the address that vector points to.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the function `main()`, `vector` is a single variable on the stack (probably 4 bytes). The address of the first of *those 4 bytes* is `&vector`. When you call `allocateArray()`, you allocate a chunk of memory on the heap. The address of *those bytes* has to be stored somewhere. The function stores that 4-byte address at the memory address passed to it, i.e., the bytes allocated on the stack.

So when we return to `main()`, the variable `vector` now points to the start of the allocated block. Because it is declared as a pointer to int, that memory will be accessed as an array of ints.

Memory addresses are just numbers like any other number. The "type" you assign to it in C just tells the compiler what you plan to do with the memory at that address. Declaring `vector` as an `int *` simply tells the compiler to fetch an `int` from memory when it sees `*vector`. The memory used to store the value of the variable itself is just the stack, exactly as if it had been a regular int, and that memory has nothing to do with the memory it points to.

We need to take the address of the stack variable because otherwise `allocateArray()` would have no way to affect the value of the variable `vector`, which is not defined in its scope, so we just have to tell it where to look.

Probably a better way to implement this is to remove that first argument to `allocateArray()` and have it return the address of the allocated block. Then we can just assign `vector` to that return value in `main()` where it's in scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main( void )
{
    int *vector = NULL;

    allocateArray(&vector,5,45);

    free( vector );

    return 0;
}
```

As you see in the main function, when the statement `allocateArray(&vector,5,45);` executed,
the memory address of a 5-element array will be passed to the vector variable; However, if you use `allocateArray(vector,5,45);`(assume that was corrected modified), then the memory address would not passed to the vector variable, because the function allocateArray(vector, 5, 45) now just passed a value of vector into the function.